# Dashboard Frameworks For Asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5

We are looking for some good dashboard frameworks for Asp.net MVC web application. We found JDash (http://www.jdash.net/) as a good option. We googled much to find out any other similar framework available.

We want the user to create their own Dashboards. Do we have any other frameworks which work with Asp.Net MVC?

Comment: For the close voters , I am only asking about tools as listed in the help topic page  "but if your question generally covers…

a specific programming problem, or
a software algorithm, or
software tools commonly used by programmers; and is
a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development
… then you’re in the right place to ask your question!"

Comment: software tools commonly used by programmers

Comment: Which means questions specifically about their usage, not recommendations about what tools to use!

Comment: @StephenMuecke ok ,then can you tell me where would be the best place to ask this question

Comment: You can try [Software Recommendations](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I don't think it will be easy to use an off the shelf solution to create a custom experience for your users. I have used DevExpress and Telerik and found them to be more trouble then they are worth because of the learning curve and they are impossible to debug.

Answer (score 1):

[Devexpress](https://www.devexpress.com/) has a big variety of MVC products including [dashboards](https://demos.devexpress.com/MVC/) you can make use of. They also offer great support for developers.

Answer (score 0):

Syncfusion has a community licence you may be eligible for https://www.syncfusion.com/products/communitylicense
Telerik Kendo UI may also be worth looking at http://www.telerik.com/kendo-ui